# How can i find the iteration of the nested foreach loop in php

Tags: php

I want to get the first element and ending element of the nested foreach loop the condition is working fine for first loop but it's not working for the second nested loop.

**PHP code**

```
$i = 0;
$len = count($category_tbl_data);
foreach($category_tbl_data as $row) {?>
   if ($i == 0) {
       // first element working fine
   }
   if ($i == $len - 1)
   {
      // last element working fine
   }

   $j=0;
   $len2 = count($services);
   foreach($services as $s){
    if($row['category']['cat_id'] == $s['Service']['category_id'])
    {
      if ($j == 0) {
       // first element working fine
    }
    if ($j == $len2 - 1)
    {
      // last element not working
    }

    }
   $j++;
  }
}
```

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc1G1.png)

Answer (score 2):

### Answered

Could there be a chance that the last element is not full-filling `if($row['category']['cat_id'] == $s['Service']['category_id'])` ?

Try placing `if ($j == 0) {}` and `if ($j == $len2 - 1){}` outside `if($row['category']['cat_id'] == $s['Service']['category_id']){}` if you want to operate on the exact first and last element of `$services`, regardless what `$s` is.

```
<?php

$len = count($category_tbl_data);
foreach($category_tbl_data as $i => $row) {
    if ($i == 0) 
    {
        // first element working fine
    }
    if ($i == $len - 1)
    {
        // last element working fine
    }

    $len2 = count($services);
    foreach($services as $j => $s){
        if ($j == 0) 
        {
            // first element 
        }
        if($row['category']['cat_id'] == $s['Service']['category_id'])
        {

        }
        if ($j == $len2 - 1)
        {
            // last element 
        }
        $j++;
    }
}
?>
```

If you want to operate on the first and last element of `$services` which satisfies `$row['category']['cat_id'] == $s['Service']['category_id']`, you should pass the array once beforehand to find out the exact indices of them first.

```
<?php
$len = count($category_tbl_data);
foreach($category_tbl_data as $i => $row) {
    if ($i == 0) 
    {
        // first element working fine
    }
    if ($i == $len - 1)
    {
        // last element working fine
    }

    $len2 = count($services);
    $first = -1;
    $last = -1;
    foreach($services as $j => $s)
    {
        if($row['category']['cat_id'] == $s['Service']['category_id'])
        {
            if($first < 0)
            {
                $first = $j;
            }
            $last = $j;
        }
    }
    foreach($services as $j => $s){

        if($row['category']['cat_id'] == $s['Service']['category_id'])
        {
            if ($j == $first) 
            {
                // first element
            }
            if ($j == $last)
            {
                // last element 
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
```